# Using inheritance with nested master pages

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

**Summary of problem:**

I would like to create a master page, and from that a nested master page, and finally from that a webform that inerhits from the nested master page.

The master page should have property **Foo** and the nested master page should have property **Bar**

Ideally I would like for the webform to have access to those inherited properties, however when I change my webform's code-behind class from **System.Web.UI.Page** to **NestedMasterPage1** I'm getting an RTE saying that I need to extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'.

I bet there is a better way of doing this, but so far I can't find one.

Thanks for reading!!!

**Steps to reproduce:**
Create **Site1.Master** and from that page create **NestedMasterPage1.master** and from that create **WebForm1.aspx**.

On the codebehind for Site1.Master create public Property **Foo**

On the codebehind for **NestedMasterPage1.master** create Public Property **Bar**

Change the codebehind for **NestedMasterPage1** to inherit from **Site1** instead of **System.Web.UI.MasterPage**

Change the codebehind for Webform1.aspx, inheriting from **NestedMasterPage1** instead of **System.Web.UI.Page**

Everything compliles, running gets the following error:

"Parser Error Message: 'WebApplication2.WebForm1' is not allowed here because it does not extend class 'System.Web.UI.Page'."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that; pages do not inherit their master pages.

Instead, you can cast the page's `Master` property to `NestedMasterPage1` to access the master class.

Comment: This one seems to trip everyone up the first time around, and without understanding the underlying implementation it can be a little counter-intuitive that the masterpage is a child of the page.